# Convert an existing s3 bucket policy into a terraform-managed policy?

Tags: terraform, s3

I have a large bucket policy historically maintained by hand.

I'd like to move it into CI/terraform (for the policy maintenance), but I don't want TF to own the bucket itself.

Is there any way to have TF "import" the huge existing policy and generate the TF file for it?  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, since the bucket is already there with the policy you can run the below command to get the policy inside the tf state

```
$ terraform import aws_s3_bucket_policy.allow_access_from_another_account my-s3-bucket-name
```

Once the policy is there in the TF, run the below code in `main.tf`

So that it will match with the policy in the state and in the plan it will display if it matches with the state or not.

> //resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {
> //  bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket"
> //}
>
> ```
>     resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "allow_access_from_another_account" {
>       bucket = "enter the bucket ID from the portal"
>       policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.allow_access_from_another_account.json
>     }
>     
>     data "aws_iam_policy_document" "allow_access_from_another_account" {
>       statement {
>         principals {
>           type        = "AWS"
>           identifiers = ["123456789012"]
>         }
>     
>         actions = [
>           "s3:GetObject",
>           "s3:ListBucket",
>         ]
>     
>         resources = [
>           "arn for aws bucket",
>         ]
>       }
>     }
> ```

Comment: Thanks accepting as this is the right TF answer.  Also though, I found this CLI command is an easy way there from CI (not as good, but quick to implement).  `aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket <bucket> --policy file://<local-file>.json`